# Office 365 federation with custom STS

Tags: asp.net, powershell, azure, office365

I have application with local relating database. This db have info about all users (login, password, name,etc...). I try integrated my app with o365. I use Graph Api to create user in Azure domain. (I use graph like this solution: [link](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Write-Sample-App-for-79e55502)). 
This step works perfectly. If i create user in my app interface, my app create user in DB, then create user in Azure AD.(Example: if I create user with name Bill92, in AD creating user Bill92@domain.onmicrosoft.com).
My app contains custom STS, this module authenticated my user.

Then I would set up the azure domain, so that as the login "Bill92@domain.onmicrosoft.com" panel office , office redirect to my app STS. In this [site](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn641269.aspx), author descriptions how my STS schould creating SAML reponse (with claims UPN and ImmutableID).I can not check this solution because I can not install PowerShell(Errors).

In short, what I need: If you enter a user login with my domain, office go to my STS for authorization token. Exactly like this [post](http://zamd.net/2013/02/08/federating-a-custom-sts-with-office-365-azure-active-directory/).

My question:

1) Before i resolve the problem with PowerShell, i ask: This command `Set-MsolDomainAuthentication`, help to resolve this problem and redirect offce authentication to my STS?

2) Is it possible to do what this command in a different way? Maybe in graph api or `manage.windowsazure.com` administration panel?

3) Maybe there's another way to accomplish what I want?